# moving around the stage(doing a full lap) before ending at a certain point

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I make that the object that I click, start moving in circles ( 2,3 ) around the stage 
before arriving at its end position.Like in this picture[image]

the way I figured out it could be is something like this:

```
private function onClick( ev:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var currentObj:Sprite = ev.currentTarget as Sprite;

        TweenLite.to(currentObj, 1, {x:first_X, y:first_Y, onComplete:goToPosition2 });

        function goToPosition2():void
        {
            TweenLite.to(currentObj, 1, {x:secontd_X, y:second_Y, onComplete:goToPosition3 });
        }

        function goToPosition3():void
        {
            TweenLite.to(currentObj, 1, {x:third_X, y:third_Y, onComplete:goToPosition4 });
        }
        ..
        ..
        .
        .
        .
        //and so on and so on

    }
```

yet I somehow feel that this is very wrong way of doing it.

Comment: I feel like now would be a good time to implement high school geometry and trig. Write the equation of a circle as a function with r and the circle center as arguments. Then, you can call the function to get the positions as it moves around the circle, and then as it spirals out (larger circle with a different center).

Comment: Why do you think that your way is wrong? For an irregular path you'd HAVE to do something like your idea. For geometrically REGULAR paths (which, of course, can still be complex in appearance) there must be many ways. See my answer for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit interesting, another way of solving it can be to create a movieclip that contains a 'handle' clip inside that follows a motion path. Call this the 'driver clip'.

Then to get a shape/another moiveclip to follow along it, start the driver clip playing at frame 1 and add an event handler. In the event handler, on every frame sync the x and y of the object you want to the driver clip's handle clip inside. Also can set the visibility of that handle clip to false to hide it. When the driver clip reaches the end frame, you can remove the event listener and the shape will be in its finish position.

This method would work for a very irregular shape that would take too long to manually plot in code (assuming you're using the flash ide).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: contain your object within a parent MovieClip, near its periphery. On click, rotate the parent and also increase its scale, so that your object traces a spiral path.